# How to extract from Outlook emails sent to an email address?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, windows-services

We're using Microsoft Outlook 2003 and I'd like to create an Email Group e.g. "dev-issues@company.com" so that people can send emails to this email address.

I'd need to export the emails to an application and process it further.

So I thought to create a windows service, connect to the Outlook engine and using polling I'd figure out which emails were sent to this Email Address.

How would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an [Outlook Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx) or a [VBA script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx) to run on a dedicated machine to monitor the Inbox.

Both can do pretty much the same things, but there are some differences. There's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx) that offers some guidance on how to select an API.

If you have Exchange Server, you could probably use the Exchange API in a windows service as you suggested.

Comment: 3 solutions you suggested. We can't use Exchange Server as ours is not configured to expose any web service. How would you create an add-in?

Comment: @William: You would ask Google.